# Gridlines Visible in android background even for white background

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-xml

***Problem***::

1. Whenever i am running my app on my emulator(`I have set Background
   to #FFFFFF`), I can see light grid-lines in the background.
2. Clearly its not 100% white background.
   Why is this happening ?
3. Is this just the behavior of emulator or Theme behavior
4. Has anyone other than me noticed this ?

---

### How can i get 100% white background ?

---

***Theme i am using***::

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

**SNAPSHOT**:: (Check the white region in the image)

[image]

Comment: did you test it on a device?

Comment: @ Raghunandan ...... I have not tested it on device yet ..... I noticed similar behaviour for black background too

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto ... Please check the snapshot

Comment: The code that produced the snapshot would be helpful (XML layout, I assume).